# What is the correct way of using a fixed precision number in rust-postgres?

Tags: postgresql, rust

What is the correct way of defining and passing a fixed precision number (decimal or numeric in Postgres) to a insert in rust-postgres?

```
transaction.execute("INSERT INTO commons_account(
            display_name, blocked, balance, blocked_balance, password, salt)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);", &[&"bob", &false, &0, &0, &"dfasdfsa", &"dfsdsa"]).unwrap();
```

Both balance and blocked balance are `numeric` and running this code gives this error

```
thread 'test' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: WrongType(Numeric)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Numeric` is not in the [supported types](http://sfackler.github.io/rust-postgres/doc/v0.10.2/postgres/types/trait.ToSql.html).
You need to implement the trait ToSql yourself with something like:

```
struct Float64(f64);

impl ToSql for Float64 { // Or a fixed-precision type.
    to_sql_checked!();

    fn to_sql<W: Write + ?Sized>(&self, _: &Type, mut w: &mut W, _: &SessionInfo) -> Result<IsNull> {
        let num = 0;
        w.write_f64::<BigEndian>(num)?;
        *self = Float64(num);
        Ok(IsNull::No)
    }

    accepts!(Type::Numeric);
}
```

Comment: I just discovered that Rust does not have a built-in decimal type, this just made everything more difficult

Comment: @ibrabeicker, There's https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3wfhro/decimal_d128_type_for_rust_for_decimal_floating/; see also https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3wubj0/numeric_types_in_rust/